# Build process in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, build

How to run specific target of build.xml from eclipse. I am making some changes in my war project and using sysdeo tomcat plugin under eclipse to start and stop services but the problem is now i want to call targets of build to reflect new changes and i have no idea what to do
Thanks

Comment: can any one please tell me is there any way to reload the context after performing any target?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the main Menu -> Window -> Show View, select Ant; drag and drop you build.xml into the ant-view. After that you can execute ant-targets by double clicking them.

Comment: can you please tell me is there any way to reload the context after performing any target

Comment: @Kuri I'm not sure which context you mean, if you modify sources outside eclipse you need to do a refresh (project -> context menu)

Comment: No dear, i mean when i am changing source file and building it. Then it should reflect in tomcat itself, without restarting the tomcat. For that context needs to be re-loadable. Now I have configured my tomcat as re-loadable under context.xml and its working now. Thanks for the time.